# Probably True/False

Tags: word-usage

> If something is probably true.
>
> Isn't it is equally likely to be false?

I was going through an online reasoning English Test where I had to read a passage and answer the choices whether they were probably true, definitely true, probably false, definitely false.

My dilemma is if something is probably true.

That implies, I am not certainly sure whether it is true or not . And which then can be equally likely to be false.

Comment: "probably true" means that a statement is more likely true than false, not 50-50 but maybe 70-30.

Comment: I think "probably" is a way to say 'likely" so possibilities to happen are high.

Comment: If something is *probably* true, by definition that means it's more likely to be true than not. On the other hand, although if we're told something is *possibly* true we often assume that it's more likely *not* to be true, that's not always the case. We tend to make that assumption simply because if the speaker chose *possibly* over *probably*, he did so specifically because he *didn't* want to say it was "more likely than not" (and if he didn't want to give that impression, possibly/probably it was because he believed the "opposite" likelihood to be applicable).

Comment: Looks like, I get the gist.

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after "isn't". Are those sentences really in the test? The first line isn't a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you believe something is **probably** true, by definition, you're indicating that you think it's *more likely to be true than false*. As you say, this implies that you're not *certain* that it's true -- but you still suspect "true" is more likely than "false".

To indicate that something is equally likely to be true or false, there would have to be another answer choice on the test, such as "unable to tell".

Comment: There was another option(Not enough information).

Comment: Then that would be the one to choose if there is not enough evidence in the passage to support either "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0):

> Probable: likely to be or become true or real (Merriam-Webster)

If something is probably true, then it is more likely to be true, than to be false

The opposite would be

> improbable: unlikely to be true or to occur